# Synchronizing the environments - Folders, dlls, files

Tags: windows

We want to Sync our dev environment to Prod.  There are different kinds of files dlls, aspx, html, txt, folders, subdirectories.  Is there any tool that can give us report that states these files are out of sync based on modified, created date or version

Is it possible to copy out of sync files from one location to other.  We are using windows server 2003

Thanks!
Kris

Comment: You need source control. I'd recommend using SVN. Git is your other option.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of version control / file comparison tools.. I personally like Scooter Soft's Beyond Compare http://www.scootersoftware.com, it's a bit simple (which is why i like it), then there's this one, which i use at my day job: diffMerge http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/. Honestly, there's a ton of tools for this, each with there different pro's / con's.. it will depend on the granular needs of your situation.

Google  "file comparison tool"